# PHP Ajax - How to send a HTTP request and show the data

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am having two files right now.
One is the api called "sqltest.php"

When I open  on my server, I get some API output like this:

```
["39","blah"]
```

My client.php contains the jquery ajax code to receive that data and display it properly in the web browser.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>


  <h2> Client example </h2>
  <h3>Output: </h3>
  <div id="output">this element will be accessed by jquery and this text replaced</div>

  <script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

  $(function () 
  {
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // 2) Send a http request with AJAX http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    $.ajax({                                      
      url: 'sqltest.php',                  //the script to call to get data          
      data: "",                        //you can insert url argumnets here to pass to api.php
                                       //for example "id=5&parent=6"
      dataType: 'json',                //data format      
      success: function(data)          //on recieve of reply
      {
        var id = data[0];              //get id
        var vname = data[1];           //get name
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------
        // 3) Update html content
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------
        $('#output').html("<b>id: </b>"+id+"<b> name: </b>"+vname); //Set output element html
        //recommend reading up on jquery selectors they are awesome 
        // http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/
      } 
    });
  }); 

  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, the code does not work. I think it is outdated since I found it on a very old article that had exactly what I was looking for.

What can I do to make the code work? I have downloaded the newest slim and compressed jquery.js and put it on my web server.

Thanks

Comment: Got an error on console? Does the ajax request reach the endpoint?

Comment: The page just shows the normal HTML as if the data is empty. no error in the web browser

Comment: You could't see the error on web browser itself. If you're using chrome, there is a console for debugging js. Open it by clicking on `F12`, then click on network tab. Try to click refresh page again and see either the request really reach the endpoint or not

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just posted what my console is saying. It was actually throwing out an error!

Comment: Glad to hear that and you're welcome. However, you can updating your question(to include the console's log)

Answer (score 1):

OK Problem solved. I was using the **slim version of ajax**.

After googling the exact error ( I didn't even know that I could look it up in the console, thanks for the hint ) - I found that the slim version was the culprit.

After uploading the full compressed version of jquery, my script worked.

Thanks.